# How to call WSDL inside the Worklight Adapter

Tags: javascript, json, wsdl, ibm-mobilefirst

i create a small webservice for WL adapter. i.e it shows "Hello World" in plain text format. I went through the training module how to use SOAP envelop inside the adapter. but this is different. I attach my code in jpeg frmt. any Suggestion please kindly let me know. 
There is anyother sample to call WSDL inside the adapter? Further details i have attach this link [Ref](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=450657&tstart=30)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rjy9dKP9 ... http://pastebin.com/ye7BxaeE. for code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hare mixing things together.
If you are using a web service that return a text why do you need SOAP?
SOAP is usually used to retrieve XML data.
Your returned content type should be plain.

```
function getHelloWorld() {
var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'plain',
    path : 'path/to/your/web/service'
};
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

You do not need to build a SOAP envelope, and if you do need to build one, it should not be a string, it should be an XML object (ignore the Eclipse error message).